# Python re a extra underscore

Tags: python

The test:

```
import re
m = re.match(r'\d*[a-zA-z]+', '123abc_2_1_4')
print(m.group())
```

I expect the result is '123abc' but it is '123abc_'. Why there is a extra underscore?

PS. I test under python 3.3.4 and python 2.7.6 (windows x64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're using `A-z`, and not `A-Z`. This is a larger range.

this matches everything from hex 0x41 to hex 0x61, which includes the `_`.

See: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: You beat me to adding that link to my answer. :)

Comment: @Barmar Haha, and you beat me by answering faster ;-)

Comment: I'm embarassed to be getting so many upvotes for an answer to a silly typo question, so I upvoted you just to make up for it.

Answer (score 9):

The regexp should be:

```
r'\d*[a-zA-Z]+'
           ^
```

If you look at an [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll see a number of punctuation characters between the uppercase and lowercase letters, and you were matching them as well as letters.